# Как настроить цвет голой консоли linux (ubuntu server)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сервер, vim, ascii

Драсте, устанавливаю линукс на полное ведро поэтому от навороченного визуала отказался. Выбрал ubuntu server. Использую редактор vim, но при работе на нем у меня глаза вытикают от стандартных цветов ASCII (именно оттенка). В терминале в графической оболочке есть настройка темы, но это же ubuntu server. Есть ли графическая оболочка в которой есть только консоль и всё, но с возможностью кастомизации? Заранее благодарен.

Comment: установите какой нибудь тайловый оконный менеджер и легковесный терминал, например, [sway](https://swaywm.org/) + [foot](https://codeberg.org/dnkl/foot)

Comment: При работе с сервером максима — "монитор нужен для установки системы". После этого монитор отрывается (в идеале — навсегда), сервер (если он домашний) запинывается в самый дальний угол, а всё управление происходит через ssh. А цвета в терминале, в котором запускается ssh, или в putty вы себе можете настроить любые.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В консоли 16 цветов (черный, красный, зеленый, желтый, синий, розовый, голубой, белый и плюс те же светлые )

Чтоб исправить оттенки 16 цветов: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Color_output_in_console_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)#%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C

> Если виртуальная консоль Linux работает через фреймбуффер, её цвета
> можно изменить. Это делается путём записи управляющей
> последовательности `\e]PXRRGGBB`, где X это 16-ричный индекс цвета 0-F
> и RRGGBB это стандартный 16-ричный код RGB.

Выставить фон и цвет текста можно попробовать командой, если терминал поддерживает 24 бит цвет

```
printf '\e]11;#004400\a' # фон
printf '\e]10;#ff0000\a' # текст
```

[Или кодами 38,48](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797#rgb-colors)

[Или в 256 цветной схеме](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797#256-colors)

```
\e[38;5;{ID}m   # текст
\e[48;5;{ID}m   # фон
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

[настройка текст](https://linuxthebest.net/kak-raskrasit-stroki-terminalakons)

[настройка видео](https://youtu.be/giAb4Ckh8BQ)

[вариант с zsh](https://losst.ru/nastrojka-zsh-i-oh-my-zsh)

еще вариант использовать mcedit из mc, в mc есть цветовые схемы